# How to create a json for python which shown change in speed every few minutes

Tags: json

I am new to json and trying to create a config.json which will be used in a python program(for esp32 board). This config.json will include various speeds at different times and this will repeat every 24 hours. For example: for first 30 minutes, speed will be 40. For next 3 hrs, speed will be 60 and so on. and after 24 hours, the cycle will repeat.
I am currently doing this, but seems like this is wrong.

{[

```
{"speed":30,"time":60},
{"speed":40,"time":60},
{"speed":60,"time":60},
{"speed":90,"time":60},
{"speed":50,"time":60}
```

]}

Here 60 stands for 60 seconds

Comment: How the file will be updated after 30 minutes, 3 hours and 24 hours ?

Comment: It should be automated, have to set that in the json or if not possible in json, then need to declare in python config_manager.py file(where rpm is declared)